# plotting residuals in R error

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot my fit in R and I I get the following error:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

Here is my code:

```
exercise <- as.factor(c(10, 10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 20, 20))
time <- c("pm", "am", "am", "pm", "am", "pm", "pm", "am")
glucose <- c(71.5, 103, 83.5, 126, 125.5, 129.5, 95, 93)

fit1 <- aov(glucose ~ exercise + time)
summary(fit1)



par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
plot(fit1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure `time` is a factor.

```
time <- as.factor(c("pm", "am", "am", "pm", "am", "pm", "pm", "am"))
```

Then your plot will work. Looks like `aov` gets a bit confused when you pass a character vector.